# Is it possible to preload multiple streams with Exoplayer and Play multiple Videos simultaneously

Tags: android, exoplayer

We are thinking to use Exoplayer in our App. Things I would like to know:

1. if it is possible to preload videostreams with Exoplayer and then hand them over to the player?
2. Is it possible to play more than one Video on a view?
3. Is it possible to unhook the player from one View and connect it to another?

Comment: Any solution regarding preload multiple streams?